# How to add large ranges to UFW in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: ip, ufw

I know how to add all from a 111.222.63.xx:

```
sudo ufw allow from 111.222.63.0/24
```

But say I want to allow all from 111.222.xxx.xxx so all from 111.222.1.X all from 111.222.2.x, etc. How would would I do that, I tried all sorts of combinations, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

The `/24` decides the range. If you want to allow all from 111.222.X.Y, use `/16`: `111.222.0.0/16`. This is [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). In an IP address `W.X.Y.Z`, each of W, X, Y and Z uses 8 bits (an octect). The `/24` is the mask, which decides how many bits of the address, starting from W, is to be considered for an operation. So `/24` means the first three octects, W, X and Y. `/16` is the first two octects, W and X, and so on.